# Invalid Activity ID when updating an activity

Tags: java, botframework

I'm trying to **update an existing Activity** that was previously sent to an MS Teams channel from my bot (for that I'm using the activity that is triggered when the user clicks on a button on the Hero Card) but the SDK keeps telling me that **the activity ID is invalid**. (***Status code 400, Invalid Activity ID***.) I need to do that so I can update the message according to different outcomes of when the buttons are pressed.

I'm using the Java SDK's method called [updateActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.bot.connector.rest.restconversations.updateactivity?view=botbuilder-java#com-microsoft-bot-connector-rest-restconversations-updateactivity(java-lang-string-java-lang-string-com-microsoft-bot-schema-activity)) from `com.microsoft.bot.connector:bot-connector:4.0.0-a1` which calls this [Bot Framework REST API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#update-activity).

I've tried as well with an `AdaptiveCard` (instead of `Hero Card`) with the latest version (`com.microsoft.connector:bot-connector:4.14.2`) but I get the same result back.

Some observations I noticed while troubleshooting this: every time I click on a Hero Card button, my service receives an activity with type text which **has always a different ID**.
Also, when I create the initial Activity with the buttons, that does not have any ID set, so I assume that that autogenerated on MS Teams side.

I hope this is clear, if not I can try to explain the issue further.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Fullstack trace of the error:

```
2022-08-01T11:57:07,560 ERROR [http-nio-8089-exec-1] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Status code 400, {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid activity ID 1:1V-DsOtKiIRLIEcpuZ-yTqfutdtrBN1346dtc-FWORtukjM-KyWqOEr-pbKgucf_tuMoutHkw66r7BTcMIjxI3Q"}}] with root cause
com.microsoft.bot.connector.models.ErrorResponseException: Status code 400, {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid activity ID 1:1V-DsOtKiIRLIEcpuZ-yTqfutdtrBN1346dtc-FWORtukjM-KyWqOEr-pbKgucf_tuMoutHkw66r7BTcMIjxI3Q"}}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.azure.AzureResponseBuilder.build(AzureResponseBuilder.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl.updateActivityDelegate(ConversationsImpl.java:612)
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl.access$300(ConversationsImpl.java:48)
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl$17.call(ConversationsImpl.java:597)
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl$17.call(ConversationsImpl.java:593)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10195)
    at com.company.msbot.service.bot.BotServiceImpl.updateCard(BotServiceImpl.java:173)
    at com.company.msbot.controller.CommandsController.commands(CommandsController.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.company.msbot.util.HttpLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpLoggingFilter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

I had to use the Activity's property called [ReplyToId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.activity.replytoid?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0) (which is the ID of the previous activity where my activity is a response to).
I wish [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.bot.connector.rest.restconversations.updateactivity?view=botbuilder-java#com-microsoft-bot-connector-rest-restconversations-updateactivity(java-lang-string-java-lang-string-com-microsoft-bot-schema-activity):%7E:text=ResourceResponse%3E%20updateActivity(String%20conversationId%2C%20String-,activityId,-%2C%20Activity%20activity)) was more clear since I wasted so much time on this.